# Get subdomain name with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working in a site where each user has own subdomain.
And i need that user can only see some images, depending on the subdomain name.
So for example:
user1.domain.com should get images inside a folder root/images/user1/
and
user2.domain.com should get images inside a folder root/images/user2/

I use similar like this:

```
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^temp\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /logo-base.png [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/access_temp_files/$1 -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /access_temp_files/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/access_temp_files/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pic-base.png [L]
```

in this case when url is temp.domain.com/image.png it gets the image at root/access_temp_files/image.png and if do not exists print pic-base.png at root/

So i need the same thing but i need to get the subdomain name
and use it in diferent places, for example replacing "temp" and "access_temp_files", like this:

```
# replacing "temp" with subdomain name in: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^temp\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(subdomainname)\.domain\.com$ [NC]

# replacing "access_temp_files" with subdomain name in: RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/access_temp_files/$1 -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/(subdomainname)/$1 -f
```

How can i get subdomainname in .htaccess file?

I hope that is not too confusing to understand :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules:

```
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^temp\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /logo-base.png [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /%1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /pic-base.png [L]
```

Comment: thank you for answer. I'm not understanding where is the subdomain name in your example. in this `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^temp\.domain\.com$ [NC]` "temp" should be subdomain name. Thank you.

Comment: First part of subdomain is captured from `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)` condition which makes `%1` as `temp` for subdomain=`temp.domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking about how to do this with .htaccess but I, personally, would create that functionality with [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html). That way, you can specify the document root for a particular subdomain. Then you could put a separate .htaccess in each subdomain's folder or you can put a global one in the parent folder of the subdomain folders.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /root/images/user1/
ServerName user1.domain.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /root/images/user2/
ServerName user2.domain.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but i don't know how to work with virtualhost. I don't know much about .htaccess files, etc.

Comment: @Pedro It's very simple. You just put code, like the above, in your httpd.conf file.